# Read data from another website

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

If I have a website, how can I display data from a different website?

For example, if I have www.example.com and I want to display the sentence "I have X apples", where X is populated from www.AppleNumber.com, which I know the format of (the X I want will always be in a div named AppleNum formatted `number: X` )

How can I go about this?

The *actual* problem I want is to read from a Chrome extension's web page to see how many installations it has, but I'm certainly okay with answers to the simplified version.

I'm only adding tags I'm thinking of, don't limit your answers based on that.

Comment: You want to make cross-origin request on client side?

Comment: try to be specific with your issue. Term you are looking from is web scraping. I won't suggest that. Use API instead(if the other site is providing).

Comment: @unixamrmy I do own the server, if that would help.

Comment: @Jigar, I can add a scraping tag. The other website is Google web store, but I'm not seeing an API for extensions.

Comment: Google Web Store ? You want to add extensions in the store ? you want list extensions from the store ? I highly doubt google would allow that. Its forking in a way.

Comment: I want to see how many users have installed a given extension, per my edit shortly after posting.

Comment: You can only do that if Chrome is installed on your webserver, otherwise accessing `chrome://extensions` via PHP won't do anything for you.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#checkstatus I am not sure which status it returns, only the `uploading status` or the `extension status`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
    $apples = file_get_contents("http://www.AppleNumber.com/?AppleID=3");
    preg_match("/<div id='AppleNum'>(\d+)<\/div>/", $apples, $Matches);

    var_dump($Matches);
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uK6oR4/1

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake in my original answer.

Comment: I should be able to modify this to make it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think this might solve your problem:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
    }
}
```

From: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

With this you can get the output of a website, like reading a txt-file.

I don't know if this will works with a Chrome extension's website.

Comment: Please quote relevant information from the source you're linking to. This to prevent link rot.

Comment: This looks like it would work for an offline solution, but it doesn't seem like I would be able to deploy this on a website / server to update on page refresh. Am I mistaken?